# PayPal button - Add custom property to be sent back from IPN listener

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I need to add a custom key to my PayPal button that gets returned with a value from the IPN Listener.  My current PayPal code is below.  Can I add a custom key/property to the `src` url or the paypal.Buttons script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank" />

     <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MyID_here&currency=USD" 
       data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
     <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'paypal',

        },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '9.99'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the purchase_units object, you can supply a custom_id

It is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit

Comment: Would it be configured like my answer below?  Can I replace "custom_id" with anything?

Comment: custom_id is a specific, documented parameter name. See the API reference link.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation at the link that you provided multiple times.  I quoted the documentation for `custom_id` in my answer below.   It looks like PayPal has recently decided to change how their buttons work.  Many of the buttons are now labeled "Legacy" status.  The code I'm using seems to be from a new system.  I'm not sure if the REST API documentation at the link is directly comparable to the client side JavaScript.

Comment: The current buttons use the v2/checkout/orders API specification.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the PayPal documentation:

> custom_id string The API caller-provided external ID. Used to
>   reconcile API caller-initiated transactions with PayPal transactions.
>   Appears in transaction and settlement reports. Maximum length: 127

So, I guess it would be added like this:

```
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '9.99'
                },
                custom_id: {
                    value: 'my_Custom_Value'
                }
            }]
```